# Algorithm for grouping many singly linked lists

Tags: algorithm, grouping, hierarchy, singly-linked-list

I have a data set that consists of objects with the form:

```
    A -> Some parent    (E.g. A -> null)
    B -> Some parent    (E.g. B -> D)
    C -> Some parent    (E.g. C -> A)
    D -> Some parent    (E.g. D -> null)
    E -> Some parent    (E.g. E -> A)
    F -> Some parent    (E.g. F -> G)
    G -> Some parent    (E.g. G -> D)
    H -> Some parent    (E.g. H -> C)
    I -> Some parent    (E.g. I -> G)
    J -> Some parent    (E.g. J -> null)
```

I want all the grouped linked lists, something like the following:

```
    A <- C <- H
    ^-E

    J

    D <- B
    ^- G <- F
       ^- I
```

Is there a general algorithm to solve the problem of grouping the singly-linked lists that will perform better than pure brute force?

The use case for me here is that, given `G`, how can I get:

```
    D <- B
    ^- G <- F
       ^- I
```

in an efficient way.

Comment: What is your input data structure?

Comment: Each data structure is an object that contains an ID, some data, and an ID of another object.

Comment: OK, but what's your overall data structure? For example: is it an array? (What I really want to know is: given the ID of an object, can you efficiently find the entry corresponding to that object?)

Comment: Yep, I can use the ID of an object and use that ID to access the data and pointer in a map.

Answer (score 1):

1. Construct an array of 2-element structures, in which the first element is the destination and the second is the source:

   ```
   (null, A),
   (   D, B),
   (   A, C),
   (null, D),
   (   A, E),
   (   G, F),
   (   D, G),
   (   C, H),
   (   G, I),
   (null, J)
   ```
2. Sort this array by the first element:

   ```
   (null, A),
   (null, D),
   (null, J),
   (   A, C),
   (   A, E),
   (   C, H),
   (   D, B),
   (   D, G),
   (   G, F),
   (   G, I)
   ```
3. And then recursively reveal the whole graph, using the initial data and the array just created:

   ```
   a.
         ^- G

   b.
         ^- G <- F
            ^- I

   c.    D
         ^- G <- F
            ^- I

   d.    D <- B
         ^- G <- F
            ^- I
   ```